# returning and recieving boolean

Tags: javascript, boolean

I need help with returning a boolean value from my validateItems() function. And my addPatrons() function (which calls the validateItems() function) must receive the boolean value returned by validateItems() and store it in a variable named "isValid". Then i need to Check the value of isValid if it is true, then use $('myform').submit(); but if it is false, then display "Patron Not Added!" in the endmessage.

this is what i have so far, its not finished because i am lost. its probably something simple but i am not getting it.

```
var validateItems = function () {
        var firstName = $("firstname").value;
        $("firstname").focus(); //puts crusor on field

        if (firstName == "") {
            $("firstnameerror").innerHTML = "Enter First Name"
        }

        var lastName = $("lastname").value;

        if (lastName == "") {
            $("lastnameerror").innerHTML = "Enter Last Name"
        }

        var addpatron = function (validateItems) {
            var isValid =

                if () {
                    $("myform").submit();
                }
            else
            if () {
                $("endmessage").innerHTML = "Patron Not Added!"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var validateItems = function() {
    var formValid = true
    var firstName = $("firstname").value;
    $("firstname").focus(); //puts crusor on field

    if(firstName == "") {
        $("firstnameerror").innerHTML = "Enter First Name"
        formValid = false
    }

    var lastName = $("lastname").value;

    if(lastName == "") {
        $("lastnameerror").innerHTML = "Enter Last Name"
        formValid = false
    }
    return formValid
}

var addpatron = function(validateItems) {
    var isValid = validateItems ()

    if (isValid ){
        $("myform").submit();
    }
    else if (){
        $("endmessage").innerHTML = "Patron Not Added!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your form element as below

```
<form onsubmit="return validateAndSubmit();" >...</form>
```

And use the validate function as below

```
validateAndSubmit(){
    let invalid = false;

    if(firstName == "") invalid = true;
    if(lastName == "") invalid = true;

    if(invalid) return false; // prevents the form from submitting
    else return true; // submits the form
}
```

**EDIT 1**

if you don't have to submit the form literally, but only perform an operation on submit you can return false always.

```
validateAndSubmit(){
    event.preventDefault();
    let invalid = false;

    if(firstName == "") invalid = true;
    if(lastName == "") invalid = true;

    if(!invalid){
        addPatron(); // perform add operation only when form is valid
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have made the following changes.

1. returning false always.
2. If not invalid calling the addPatron() function
3. Added event.preventDefault() for additional event bubbling to stop.

Comment: okay thanks, so for the addpatron function, that one is supposed to receive the boolean from the validateItems function so the form can submit if all data is entered or prevent the form from submitting if invalid.  Iam having trouble with adding info that is supposed to be in there.